# Letter Z drawn with stars python

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I'm new in python and I'm struggling with one problem. I have to make letter Z with stars(*) using for loop. I am working in Python 2.7. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you given the number of start to use on the top and bottom stroke? Is the diagonal stroke to be at a 45 degree angle? Is this to be a function or a code segment? Can three for-loops be used or must there be only one? Is this letter to be printed or stored for later use? Finally, what have you tried--please show us some code.

Comment: are you struggling to start coding? or struggling with some part of the problem? If you are working with python 2.7, please show some code, something, for us to start with.. If it's `for` loop syntax that you need help with, check this out: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop, start with one line, etc, if you get stuck, click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40518628/edit) button on your question, add some code you've written, then we can help you further. Also, this has a good starting point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736522/creating-shapes-or-letters-using-python

Comment: I won't do this because I would just received ten downvotes, but I'm really tempted to answer with "Yes, I can help.".

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution:

```
def print_z():
    base = '***************'
    print base
    for i in reversed(range(0, len(base))):
        void = ' '.join(['' for j in range(0,i+1)])
        print void + '*'
    print base
```

One improvement is to give the width of the base as an argument:

```
def print_z(width):
    base = '*'.join(['' for i in range(0, width+1)])
    print base
    for i in reversed(range(0, width)):
        void = ' '.join(['' for j in range(0,i+1)])
        print void + '*'
    print base
```

It outputs something like this:

```
**********
         *
        *
       *
      *
     *
    *
   *
  *
 *
*
**********
```

Comment: Do you really want to give a complete answer to a vague question showing so little work?

Comment: @RoryDaulton while I agree, down-votes are unwarranted on the answer and should be directed to the question only.

Comment: @RoryDaulton is it against SO rules? or against SO "spirit"? Also I don't think that deserves to be down voted.

Comment: @EmileBergeron: That is not what I have seen in other similar situations, including ones I where I answered such a question and got downvotes. Is there some official policy on this issue somewhere? (This is a real question, not snark.) I'll change my vote if I see adequate evidence, of course.

Comment: @RoryDaulton it's really unfortunate to receive down-votes when trying to help. It's true that by answering a bad question, it kind of do the opposite to the community. The best would be to flag, and down-vote the question. Inform the user with a comment is also good.

Comment: @RoryDaulton [Is it okay to downvote answers to bad questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions)

Comment: @EmileBergeron: OK, that link convinced me. I'll change my downvote to an upvote. I wish I could give that link to all who downvoted me when I started here and gave answers to such questions.

Comment: @RoryDaulton don't mind down-votes as it takes 5 to counter 1 upvote. If your answer is down-voted to hell, maybe deleting is the best option (you even receive a [badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure) for that!)